# The average number of transitions to a particular state from only two particular states.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I know that in a Markov chain, $$\mathbf{N} = (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{Q})^{-1}$$ gives a matrix to calculate the expected number of times before absorption that a particular [transient] state is visited, beginning from a particular state. (where $\mathbf{Q}$ is the sub-matrix of the transition matrix corresponding to the transient states).

Now I am interested in the expected number of times that a particular state is visited ONLY from two other specific transient states (for example, how many times on average I go to state 2 from state 1 or state 3?). I don't want to count indirect transitions. Assume state 4 is the absorbing state in this example.

Shall I add together the corresponding two elements in $\mathbf{N}$ (elements in row 1 col 2 and row 3 col 2)?

Comment: If you want the expected number of times you use the $(1,2)$ link before being trapped somewhere, you could write it as $\sum_{i=1}^{N_1} Z_i$ where $N_1$ is the random number of times in state 1 before being trapped, and $Z_i$ is an indicator variable that is $1$ if you go to $2$ immediately after the $i$th time being in 1, and $0$ else.  So $\sum_{i=1}^{N_1} Z_i = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} Z_i 1\{N_1\geq i\}$ and in fact $Z_i$ is independent of the event $1\{N_1 \geq i\}$ so $E[\sum_{i=1}^{N_1} Z_i ] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} E[Z_i]P[N_1\geq i] = E[Z_i]E[N_1]$.

Comment: I suppose I should do that for link (3,2) as well. right? BTW I have worked on your energy-delay tradeoff papers (cited in 2014) and have read your book on stochastic optimization 2010 :)

Comment: Yes, the number of $(1,2)$ uses plus the number of $(3,2)$ uses gives you the total, and the expectation of the sum is the sum of expectations.  I'm surprised you happened to know of my work.  Thanks for the note.